# Generating a password hash similar to the one inside /etc/shadow

Tags: linux, hash, crypt

Hallo i want to make a script that hashes passwords and compares them with the ones inside /etc/shadow... But i have one hitch

The passwords at /etc/shadow usually get a strange and unique hash salt every time a new user is created how can i be able to generate a similar hash using the same password?

To be able to have identical passwords the one i have and the one at the shadow file

I have tried using perl python mkpasswd all without matching it
In particular where does the salt come from and can i change it?

Comment: The algorithm is public but I am too lazy to go look it up. IIRC the first two characters of the account name are used for the salt. The purpose of this is to make it less obvious when two users have the same password.

Comment: See `man 3 crypt` which is mentioned in `man shadow`.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is described at:
* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28C%29
or as you use Perl
* http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/crypt.html

The first couple of chars in the hash are the "salt" based on  random characters, which is used to produce different hashes for the same password to make rainbow table attacks harder.
The 13 character long DES based hashes have exact two characters as salt.

To verify a password use:    if (crypt($plaintext, $hash) eq $hash) { print("OK"); }

Answer (score 0):

The salt would be randomly generated for each username. How exactly the random salt is generated is not clear.

However, once the salt is generated by the PC, the user-supplied *PASSWORD* is suffixed with the salt value and hashed many times with a suitable hashing algorithm to generate a hash value which gets stored in /etc/shadow.

E.g. In modern Linux/Ubuntu, SHA-512 is typically used as a hashing algorithm. So, if you retrieve the *SALT* from /etc/shadow, then the hashed password can be generated as shown in the command-line snippet below:

```
mkpasswd -m sha-512 -S SALT -R 5000 PASSWORD
```

In snippet above, if you know the random *SALT* generated by the system for the user (available in /etc/shadow file) and the user-supplied *PASSWORD*, mkpasswd can calculate the hashed password which is stored in /etc/shadow for you. The default number of times the SHA-512 algorithm is supplied is 5000. mkpasswd is available in package *whois*, so if you can run the following cmd to install the tool in Linux:

```
sudo apt-get install whois
```